# Way to determine correctness of iterators order passed to function

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, iterator, c++14

There are a plenty functions in *STL* of form:

```
result_type algorithm(ForwardIterator beg, ForwardIterator end);
```

or

```
result_type algorithm(BidirectionalIterator beg, BidirectionalIterator end);
```

Is there portable and convenient way to determine, whether an `end` iterator is potentially reachable from a `beg` by simple incrementation of the former (and vice versa in case of bidirectional iterator)? How should looks like corresponding `assert(?);` on the first line of above kind of algorithms?

The intention is to detect errors like `std::list< int > l(10); std::iota(std::end(l), std::begin(l), 0);` as early as it possible until UB occures.

Are there any proposals or is there something in Range-V3 library to deal with the issue?

Comment: Think about it. How would you prove unreachability?

Comment: One spontaneous idea would be to wrap the functions with versions taking 3 arguments. The container and the 2 iterators. Then you should be able to check if both iterators belong to the same container etc. But I fear many will hate me for that idea :) Hm... yes they never learn - was the same with functions taking OUT arrays in C apis without wanting capacity either :)

Comment: @T.C. I think about internal indices for iterators (say, just for debug version of them), but it shoud double its size.

Comment: Something like I saw in *STLport* library, but it ceased to exist in public domain as I know.

Comment: If you have to work with arbitrary iterators, this is obviously impossible (since increment can execute arbitrary operations, it's trivial to show that this is equivalent to the halting problem). If you have control over the iterator you are working with, then you can embed all sorts of debugging information in there, so the answer is trivial.